# Loading Dialog Box for Webview

Tags: java, android

This things sending me crazy. My app loads webview and shows a loading dialog on the initial load. I want the loading dialog to appear each time a link is clicked or each time webview is loading. This is not happening.

Eclipse tells me onPageStarted() is not used locally, although onPageFinished() works fine!?

Can anyone see what's going wrong, I've pasted all my activity below:

```
   package com.jeh.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    WebView myWebView;
    public static final String TAG = "Main";
    public ProgressDialog progressBar; 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Remove title bar as we already have it in the web app
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //Point to the content view defined in XML
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //Configure the webview setup in the xml layout
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        //Yes, we want javascript, pls.
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "Diag Title", "Loading...");


        //Make sure links in the webview is handled by the webview and not sent to a full browser
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            //this bit causes problems, if I add @Override here it says to remove, where as the current code marks onPageStarted yellow and says it's not used locally!? - yet onPageFinsihed() below works fine?
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

                progressBar.show();
            }


             public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                 Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
                 if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                     progressBar.dismiss();
                 }
             }

        });
        //Load URL:
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");



    }
```

Comment: hey: it's @Override **public** void onPageStarted(...)

Comment: Yeah, sorry tried that too, same problem.

Comment: It's really odd because public void onPageFinished() works fine...

Comment: did you try keeping the @Override and adding import android.graphics.Bitmap; ? (Can't see it in your code)

Comment: Do'h! that was it! I rely on eclipse so much to tell me about missing imports I overlooked it when it didn't give me the hint. Thanks u so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy.
There are no

```
void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url)
```

method in a [WebViewClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html), simply use :

```
@Override
void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
```

These errors are easy to make and difficult to find. You should use @Override keyword wherever you know you're overriding a method (which would have flagged an error in your case).

Try to modify your source this way:

```
//Make sure links in the webview is handled by the webview and not sent to a full browser
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        progressBar.show();
    }

    @Override
     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
         if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
             progressBar.dismiss();
         }
     }

});
```

Comment: @badger110 hmm, very odd. Did you try to save your file? Can you update your code on your question?

Comment: Hi I've updated, if I add an @Override to the onpagestarted() it underlines in red saying 'must override or implement a supertype method' If I quick fix and remove '@Override' it underlines in yellow telling me it's not used locally, and as a result doesn't work when I test in the emulator.

Comment: @badger110 make sure Bitmap is in your imports with: import android.graphics.Bitmap; otherwise the methode signature is not recognized but please **keep using @Override** otherwise your error is still there but masked.